# systemd network issues, ' code=exited, status=1/FAILURE'

Tags: linux, systemd, ubuntu-20.04

I have an application that fails to connect with networking (that's what I assume) and throws an 'code=exited, status=1/FAILURE' error if I start it using systemd. However if i start that application manually everything works fine. Also I tested the same exact service on different vps provider and everything worked fine. Both uses ubuntu 20.04 operational system. What could be causing this issue ?

That's the last output I get before it turns off.

```
[INFO] Initializing networking...
[ERROR] Networking failed to start.  Terminating..
```

This is my .service file

```
[Unit]
Description=yesyes
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
RemainAfterExit=yes
WorkingDirectory=/opt/srv
ExecStart=/opt/srv/ragemp-server

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```